# How to refer to list-column using purrr function (map()) with varying input

Tags: r, list, purrr, tidyquant

How do I properly refer to a list-column in R, when I am using a map (or any purrr function) function and want to utilize "x" from the map function in calling the appropriate list?  For example, if I have a list of 3 (let's call it testlist) and within that list I have a series of single columns (that are dataframes).  Each column consists of a list of character vectors (in this case they are a list of symbols to be input into tq_get in tidyqant).  Below is some simplified code to help illustrate.

The following code works, but it's hardcoded:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyquant)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

str(testlist)
List of 3
 $ 2010-12-31:'data.frame': 12 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ symbol: chr [1:12] "ASH" "RS" "FUL" "RGLD" ...
 $ 2011-12-31:'data.frame': 15 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ symbol: chr [1:15] "CBT" "RS" "TCK" "MEOH" ...
 $ 2012-12-31:'data.frame': 13 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ symbol: chr [1:13] "CBT" "ATI" "RS" "SXT" ...

d <- tq_get((pull(testlist$`2012-12-31`)), 
       get  = "stock.prices",
       from = "2011-12-30",
       to   = "2013-12-31")
```

To clarify, each dataframe within the "testlist" list is labeled with a date.  In this case 2012-12-31.

However, I would like vary the date when referring to each dataframe within "testlist".  For example:

```
year <- as.Date("2012-12-31")
d <- tq_get((pull(testlist[year])), 
       get  = "stock.prices",
       from = "2011-12-30",
       to   = "2013-12-31")
```

This does not work.  I have determined that if I'm referring to a column within a dataframe this will work:

```
testlist[,as.character(year)]
```

But clearly referring a column in a dataframe is different from referring to a dateframe within a list.

Here is the expected output.  It works for the first example and does not work for the 2nd.

```
d
# A tibble: 6,526 x 8
   symbol date        open  high   low close volume adjusted
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 CBT    2011-12-30  32.2  32.4  32.0  32.1 216100     25.9
 2 CBT    2012-01-03  33.2  33.6  32.9  33.2 410500     26.8
 3 CBT    2012-01-04  33.1  33.4  32.7  33.2 502100     26.8
 4 CBT    2012-01-05  32.9  32.9  32.0  32.7 688400     26.4
 5 CBT    2012-01-06  32.8  33.1  31.7  32.8 951900     26.4
 6 CBT    2012-01-09  32.9  33.2  32.5  32.7 393100     26.4
 7 CBT    2012-01-10  33.3  33.9  33.2  33.3 306300     26.9
 8 CBT    2012-01-11  33.3  33.7  33.2  33.5 209700     27.0
 9 CBT    2012-01-12  33.7  34.4  33.4  34.3 209800     27.7
10 CBT    2012-01-13  34.0  34.2  33.3  33.9 273200     27.4
# ... with 6,516 more rows
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show what `testlist` is. Also name all packages needed to run your code. Also show expected output.

Comment: Thank you, see edits above.